# How to open multiple tabs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to input a value and use it in all the links to open in multiple tabs. But only the first link opens, not all. What should I do ?

```
 <html>

<head>
<script>
function myFunction() 
{
    var x=document.getElementById('reg').value;
    window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/195_RES/"+x+".html");
    window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/204_RES/"+x+".html");
    window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/248_RES/"+x+".html");
    window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/294_RES/"+x+".html");
    window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/335_RES/"+x+".html");

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Enter reg no<input type=text id='reg'>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `"_blank"` as the second parameter of `window.open(url,"_blank")`.It will open the urls in `new window in Crome` and `new tab Firefox`.Try this :

```
function myFunction() 
{
     var x=document.getElementById('reg').value;
     window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/195_RES/"+x+".html", "_blank");
     window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/204_RES/"+x+".html", "_blank");
     window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/248_RES/"+x+".html", "_blank");
     window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/294_RES/"+x+".html", "_blank");
     window.open("http://results.bput.ac.in/335_RES/"+x+".html", "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your popup blocker settings. i tried your code on chrome and firefox and both open multiple tabs. I clicked on the button without entering the number.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how do I make them open in tabs instead of windows ?